# Como puedo dividir un texto en 3 arreglos diferentes

Tags: javascript, string, split

Necesito obtener mi cadena, que devuelve todo en una fila y lo separa por patrones.

Por ejemplo, como se ve en el texto a continuación, necesito que si encuentra la palabra detente, corte la cadena y me la devuelva en una matriz, luego, la próxima vez que encuentre la palabra, la cortará y así sucesivamente con la tercera. cual seria andres.

Debido a que necesito separarlo en 3 arreglos, estaba tratando de hacerlo con división, pero no obtengo el resultado que necesito. Soy nuevo en javascript y tal vez haya una manera más fácil de hacerlo de lo que imagino. muchas gracias espero me puedan ayudar.

```
var texto = "Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking 
at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed 
by 
and made him stop. stop soldier, I want to ask you a question 
Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't 
seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is My husband is 
tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat 
it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written 
San Andres"


//Necesito que me devuelva asi: 
//Ejemplo: 
let primerSeccion = ["Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed by and made him stop"]
let segundaSeccion = ["I want to ask you a question Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is"]
let terceraSeccion = ["My husband is tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written San Andres"]

//Lo que intente fue lo siguiente.. 
//Si texto incluye la palabra stop. Deberia cortar la ejecucion y hasta donde llego deberia guardar en un arreglo. 
let primerSeccion = [];
let segundaSeccion = [];
let terceraSeccion = [];
//Intente varias formas que fui encontrando.. Pero ninguna se acerca un poco a lo que necesito.
console.log(texto[0,6] === "Catherine")
console.log(texto.includes('stop'))
for (let index = 0; index < texto.length; index++) {
  return texto.includes("stop")
  
}
```

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Veo que solo quieres recortar oraciones de acuerdo a un patrón, no es difícil, a continuación un ejemplo, cabe recalcar que que se quiere volver a elegir otro patrón o volver a buscar la coincidencia solo es llamar nuevamente a la función 'cortar'.

```js
const texto = "Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed by and made him stop. stop soldier, I want to ask you a question Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is My husband is tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written San Andres"
const primeraPalabra = "stop"
const cortar = word => texto.split(word)
const resultado = cortar(primeraPalabra)
let cont = 0;


for(i in resultado)
{
    cont++
    if(cont != resultado.length)
    {
        let parrafo = "<p>" + resultado[i] + "stop <p>"
        document.getElementById("textoSeparado").innerHTML += parrafo
    }
    else
    {
        let parrafo = "<p>" + resultado[i] + "<p>"
        document.getElementById("textoSeparado").innerHTML += parrafo
    }
    

}
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="textoOriginal">
            <p>
                Catherine was there Sitting under a laurel Looking 
                at the coolness of the falling waters Suddenly a soldier passed by and made him stop. stop soldier, I want to ask you a question Haven't you seen my husband who went to war one day? I haven't seen her husband I don't even know who (how) he is My husband is tall and blond, as handsome as you are. And on the tip of the hat it has San Andres written And on the tip of his sword is written San Andres
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="textoSeparado">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta no está bien definida!! no sé de javaScript pero igual te sugiero una idea de lógica, busca el índex_final de la palabra detente en el texto, y a partir de allí coges todo el texto desde el la primera letra hasta el índex_final encontrado antes, lo añades a un array que quieras y lo mismo con el resto del texto buscando otra vez tu palabra hasta encontrarla y repetir el proceso. Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Porque mi pregunta no esta bien definida?

Comment: @F4hdC Evita dejar comentarios en la zonas de respuesta, espera a que tengas la reputacion necesaria para poder comentar, date una vuelta en [answer].

Comment: @Kikegonzalez porque falta tu intento, donde esta el error que te sale o lo que has intentado para corregirlo. también la idea que quieres hacer no esta bien clara, o por lo menos yo no me he enterado muy bien.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia totalmente de acuerdo, pero eso mi limita mucho cuando quiero participar o aportar mi grano de arena. Un saludo.

Comment: Creo que cuando tengas 50 puntos es cuando puedes participar mejor en este sitio... todos hemos pasado por ahi... supongo que es razonable pensar que si no conoces aún este sitio y su funcionamiento y no aportas respuestas o preguntas correctas no te los ganarás, y de ahí tu limitación. Este sitio, por otro lado, no es un foro.  Es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Léete [ask], [answer], y visita bien el [help]

Comment: ahi logre editar mi pregunta espero que les sirva.